# Bloom filter in Spark does not work for me

Tags: apache-spark, bloom-filter

I try to use bloom filter in Spark 2.4.4, and it does not works for me.

I'm loading a real data in dataSet ds, and try to write it with bloom filter enabled.

```
ds.write.mode("overwrite") .option("parquet.bloom.filter.enabled#id",
"true") .option("parquet.bloom.filter.expected.ndv#id", "1000000")
.parquet("/dev/data")
```

When i check in /dev/data, i see only parquet files (4 files), i can't see any bloom filter index file. And when i load this dataSet, and i try to manipulate data with some id with some value, i don't see any difference with no bloom filter. In spark UI, i see 4 tasks (1 task by file) despite the fact i'm passing a where clause with a specific ID that is part of one file.

Can you please help me to find where is my error ? I'm not able to see lot of docs about Spark parquet bloom filter in the Internet.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to upgrade to spark 3.2+ in order to leverage this feature. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-34562